# How do I show the Image that I uploaded in the EDIT page, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this edit form and I want to show the image that I uploaded from the create form (its working thou) so when I edit a building I just want to see the old picture that I uploaded cause its not showing in the form. The edit works thou but I want to see the picture that already been uploaded. I tried using "$building->picture" but not working, the column name of my database is "picture".

here's the code

```
   @extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'Edit Building')
@section('content')

{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editbuilding',$id], 'class' => 'form' , 'files'=>'true')) !!}
<div class="container">

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Building Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('buildingname', $building->name,        array('required',
              'class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Building Name')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('Building Name') !!}
  {!! Form::file('buildingpics',
     array('onchange'=>'previewFile()')) !!}
  <img src="{{asset(''.$building->picture) }}" id="previewImg" style="height:300px; width:300px;" alt="">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Update',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
      <a href="{{route('index')}}" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Back</a>
</div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
<script type="text/javascript">

function previewFile() {
var preview = document.querySelector('#previewImg');
var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var reader  = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
  preview.src = reader.result;
}, false);

if (file) {
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
</script>
@endsection

@section('scripts')

@endsection
```

Comment: Could you do a dump of `$building->picture` and update your question with the result ?

Comment: What is your image path? Is it stored in `/public` folder only OR in any other sub directory of `public`? I mean in `/public/xx`??

Comment: public/assets @HirenGohel

Comment: Try: `<img src="{{asset('assets/'.$building->picture)}}">`

Comment: Is my comment worked?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the URL to the image in the `picture` file? If so, you can just pass that URL to the `src` of the `img` tag.

```
<img src="{{ $building->picture }}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

first choose where your file is saved. i mean the path of file where it is stored.

```
<img src="{{ url($building->picture) }}" ... />
```

if your file in public folder.

Comment: <img src="{{'assets'($building->picture) }}   its in public/assets   is this correct?   @Kuldeep Mishra

Answer (score 0):

asset() - Generate a URL to an application asset.

change name of folder_name according to your folder name if any here its inside "assets" folder

```
  @if ($building->picture)

     <img src="{{asset('assets/'.$building->picture)}}">

  @else

     <p>No image found</p>

 @endif
```